# Related powers in floating point

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754, numerical-analysis

Given runtime variable `double` values `x` and `y`, if I need to calculate:

```
double c1 = pow(x, y)
double c2 = pow(x, y + 1.0)
```

Is it generally safe from a numerical accuracy point of view to implement this as:

```
double c1 = pow(x, y)
double c2 = c1 * x;
```

You may assume that y is >= -1.0.

Comment: Do you mean `double c2 = c1 * x;` instead on the last line of code?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore - yes, thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Each step of FP math like this incurs an potential rounding error.

Consider how `y = pow(a,b)` approximates y = (a + error_a) <sup>b + error_b</sup> + error_y.
Error error_y is very sensitive to error_b, especially when y is large.

Addition can be troubling when positive y and 1.0 are of significantly different magnitudes.
When they differ a lot, `double c2 = pow(x, y) * x;` is better.

`y + 1.0` cancels out bits when `y` is near `-1.0`, `double c2 = pow(x, y + 1.0)` is better.

Whenever `y + 1.0` is exact, use `pow(x, y + 1.0)`.
When `y < 0.0`, I'd go for `pow(x, y + 1.0)`.
When `y > 1.0`, use `pow(x, y) * x`.

In general, I'd use `pow(x, y) * x` as the worse case error is likely only a few [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)s. (A few for a good `pow()` and ½ more for the `*`).  It is numerically risky to inject error in `b` of `pow(a,b)`.

---

Notes:

Take into account the worst case is when `y` is large and not infinite. This is really a small subset of all the possible `a,b` in `pow(a,b)` as the result is often 0.0 or ∞ or NaN.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can get different results using both expressions as `pow()` uses logarithms to calculate the final result, while the second case uses a mixture of logarithms (in the use of `pow()`) mixed with products.

Mathematically, both expressions

```
pow(x, y+1.0) ~= exp((y+1.0)*log(x))    /* ~= here means approximately equal, not the C operator */
```

and

```
pow(x, y+1.0) ~= pow(x, y)*x ~= exp(y*log(x))*x
```

should give you the same approximate results, but as the order and sequence of evaluations is different, you should expect *different* rounding errors to appear.

Both (`exp()` and `log()`) functions have alternatives for cases where they arguments are to close to `0.0` and `1.0`, respectively.  So, if that is the case (`x` too close to `1.0` and/or `y*log(x)` is too close to `0.0`), then it will be better to use the `log1p()` and/or `expm1()` variants)

Anyway, for your experiment, you can try both formulas, and compare results.  Even you can do it with `pow()` (and probably you'll get different results ---more accurate, as probably `pow()` will decide, at each call, which function is better to use)

Another hint is that rounding errors are relative to the numbers that are being multiplied... so if you have a `1.0E-10`% relative error in two numbers before multiplying them, the relative errors will maintain (you'll get `2.0E-10`%)  But when you subtract two approximately equal magnitudes, the relative error fires up completely (`1.0000000000003 - 1.0 == 3.0E-13` but the absolute error has maintained as it was before the adding, on `1.0E-13`)  which means the error now is `1.0E-13` for a magnitude that is `3.0E-13`, the relative error has raised to `33.0`%.  If you later use that number in a product, the relative error will go to the product, making your whole calculation useless.

Based on this principle, it seems that the second approach is better (as it has no additions)

And there's a third case, you can apply the fast [exponential algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) if you are just using plain integer exponents.

```
/* fea stands for (f)ast
 * (e)xponential (a)lgorithm (d)ouble */
double fead(double x, unsigned n)
{
    double result = 1.0;
    while (n) {
        if (n & 1)
            result *= x;
        x *= x; /* square x */
        n >>= 1; /* divide n by 2 */
    }
    return result;
}
```

Below is a complete implementation of some test cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* fea stands for (f)ast
 * (e)xponential (a)lgorithm (d)ouble */
double fead(double x, unsigned n)
{
    double result = 1.0;
    while (n) {
        if (n & 1)
            result *= x;
        x *= x; /* square x */
        n >>= 1; /* divide n by 2 */
    }
    return result;
}

/* test cases to probe */
struct test_case {
   double base; /* base */
   unsigned exp; /* exponent */
   double expctd; /* expected result */
} test_cases_start [] = {
    { 10.0,     45, 1.0E45 },
    { 2.0,      63, 9.223372036854775808E18 },
    { 3.141593, 15, 2.865819336962266259E7 },
    { 0.1,      15, 1.0E-15 },
};

int main()
{
    struct test_case *test_cases_end
        = (struct test_case *)(&test_cases_start + 1);

    struct test_case *p;

    for (p = test_cases_start;
         p < test_cases_end;
         p++)
    {
        double calc = fead(p->base, p->exp);
        double diff = calc - p->expctd;
        printf("fead(%20.17g, %u)\n"
            " calculated = %20.17g\n"
            "   expected = %20.17g\n"
            " difference = %20.17g\n"
            " rel. error = %20.17g\n",
            p->base, p->exp,
            calc,
            p->expctd,
            diff,
            diff/p->expctd);
    }
}
```

and a sample run:

```
$ fead
fead(                  10, 45)
 calculated = 1.0000000000000001e+45
   expected = 9.9999999999999993e+44
 difference = 1.5845632502852868e+29
 rel. error = 1.584563250285287e-16
fead(                   2, 63)
 calculated = 9.2233720368547758e+18
   expected = 9.2233720368547758e+18
 difference =                    0
 rel. error =                    0
fead(  3.1415929999999999, 15)
 calculated =   28658193.369622648
   expected =   28658193.369622663
 difference = -1.4901161193847656e-08
 rel. error = -5.199616389511387e-16
fead( 0.10000000000000001, 15)
 calculated = 1.0000000000000017e-15
   expected = 1.0000000000000001e-15
 difference = 1.5777218104420236e-30
 rel. error = 1.5777218104420234e-15
$ _
```